# Is there a Mac OS keyboard shortcut to dedent in iPython?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When coding in python3 in a Jupyter Notebook, one can tab indent and tab unindent (i.e. dedent) using `tab` and `shift + tab` respectively.

In iPython, I'm able to indent using `tab` but unable to dedent using `shift + tab`.  I'm wondering if there's a keyboard shortcut that maybe I don't know about that allows one to dedent in iPython?  I searched the net and stack overflow but couldn't find anything.

Otherwise when writing `functions` or `try/except` statements in iPython, I find myself backspacing four times (and sometimes more) in order to be compliant with python indentation protocols.

Comment: The opposite of indent is outdent. :-)

Comment: Does `cmd + [` and `cmd + ]` work for indenting and outdenting for you?

Comment: @KenWhite I've seen unindent, outdent and dedent (https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/programming-web-design/python/how-to-indent-and-dedent-your-python-code-139545/)

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Unfortunately not.