# How to dedent a block in Python3 under MacOS?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am learning Python3. It is executed on MacOS/Terminal by running `python3`.
I was able to execute some examples from the book "Deep Learning with Python, Second Edition", but I am stuck now at a simple editor problem:
If I enter the following statements

```
>>> with tf.GradientTape as tape:
...     tape.watch(input_const)
...     result = tf.square(input_const)
...
```

I am not able to terminate the indention block.
If I simply enter `return`, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __enter__
>>>
```

I have tried to terminate indention using `Shift [`, `Shift tab`, and `Control [`, but this does not work.
How do I dedent a block?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71595082/1987726), but without a solution.

Comment: You're exiting it correctly, otherwise nothing would be evaluated. The error is from the first line,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `tf.GradientTape` as a function.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(input_const)
    result = tf.square(input_const)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is indicating the 'with' language argument is not a proper context object. To correct this you need to call tf.GradientTape as a function like this tf.GradientTape()